# Are there any "Translation Accelerometer"?

Tags: accelerometer

I find many "Rotation Accelerometer" such as "GY-85", "GY-521", but no one for Translation.
Are there any "Translation Accelerometer", can detect the XYZ axis movement?

Comment: That's a normal accelerometer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**An accelerometer senses XYZ movement**

So if it doesn't explicitly say it is a "rotational accelerometer" then it senses XYZ acceleration. In fact "rotational accelerometer" is a strange term, normally an accelerometer senses acceleration in one, two or three directions and something which senses rotation is a gyroscope. Note that the GY-85 and GY-521 modules you mention each contain both an accelerometer and a gyroscope.

Note that acceleration is not quite the same as movement.  If you want to know the speed, you will need to integrate the acceleration signal from the accelerometer. If you want position, you'll need to integrate twice. If you want speed or position directly, without integration and the associated errors, then what you want is a GPS module.